# How to set a custom color to a XSSFCell using POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, apache-poi-4

I would like to set a custom color to a `CellStyle` in POI, but it doesn't seem to be getting applied.

I have the following code:

```
    XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(new byte[]{ (byte) 60,
                                                (byte) 120,
                                                (byte) 216 });
    
    CellStyle style = workBook.createCellStyle();
    style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
    style.setFillForegroundColor(color);
    
    XSSFCell cell = createCell(row, CellType.STRING, style, cellIndex);
```

I have the following Gradle dependencies:

```
implementation("org.apache.poi:poi:5.2.3")
implementation("org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:5.2.3")
```

If I use a different fille pattern and do something like this: `style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND)`, the background gets set, but the fill pattern is, obviously, not solid.

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: I've updated my question with these details.

Answer (score 1):

To my surprise the following works:

```
XSSFColor color = new XSSFColor(new byte[]{ (byte) 60,
                                            (byte) 120,
                                            (byte) 216 },
                                new DefaultIndexedColorMap());

CellStyle style = workBook.createCellStyle();
style.setFillPattern(FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
style.setFillForegroundColor(color);

XSSFCell cell = createCell(row, CellType.STRING, style, cellIndex);
```

Specifying a `new DefaultIndexedColorMap()` seems to solve it!

Answer (score 0):

You can create Color class of Java awt to achieve this.

```
 XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = this.createCellStyle(workbook);
 XSSFColor colorGrey = new XSSFColor(new Color(210, 210, 210));
 cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(colorGrey);
```

Comment: This won't work without a fill pattern would it?